# Japanese dictionary for Ubuntu (offline, open source)

Tags: linux, open-source, dictionary, japanese

I am looking for a Japanese↔English dictionary.

- Runs on Ubuntu
- Works offline
- Small GUI window
- Open source
- Maintained
- Example sentences shown for each word
- Bonus if it has [SKIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodansha_Kanji_Learner%27s_Dictionary#SKIP) kanji search

I have been using Gjiten, but it has not been updated since 2006, and does not have example sentences.

Gjiten seems to have 3 forks ([2ion](https://github.com/2ion/gjiten), [gjitenkai](https://github.com/odrevet/gjitenkai), [galtgendo](https://github.com/galtgendo/gjiten)) but apparently none has made much progress. [Gwaei](https://github.com/zakkudo/gwaei) has not been updated since 2013

Comment: gjitenkai had much progress these last two month. And you are forgetting Gwaei. (My favorite is gjitenkai but don't tell anyone)

Comment: @TheDrev: Thanks for the tip! :-) I will compile and try gjitenkai. What dictionary does Gwaei use?

Comment: This is not an answer per see, but more of an out of the box idea. It's actually not that difficult to hijack Rikaichan (https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/rikaichan/) code and reuse it as a more traditional dictionary (the resources are all there for offline use). With a few hours work it should be possible to convert it to a stand-alone application that looks and behaves the way you want. On the other hand, Rikaichan doesn't support all the bells and whistles, so adding example sentences and such would require some real work. On the plus side JavaScript runs on everything nowadays.